# Finding Galois group of function field extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, laurent-series, splitting-field, formal-power-series

Let $C((T))$ be the field of formal Laurent series in the variable $T$ over an algebraically closed field
$C$ of characteristic $0$.

I need to find to the Galois group of the splitting field for the following polynomial:

$F(X,T) = f(X)-T$

for $f(X) = \prod_{i=1}^r(X- \alpha_i)^{e_i}$

$\alpha_i \in C$

$e_i >= 1$

I've read somewhere that the extension degree is $lcm(e_1, \dots, e_r) $ and the Galois group is cyclic
but I can't find any proof.

Thank's :)

Comment: Decompose the polynomial in $C[[T^{1/N}]]/(T^M)$ then use Hensel lemma.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: Have you worked it out for small values of $r$ and the $e_i$’s?

Comment: Very easy to solve that in case of $r=1$ But i can't figure out how to show that for $r>1$