# Non cyclic galois extension

Tags: galois-theory, cyclic-groups, splitting-field

Let $C$ be an algebraically close field of positive characteristic $p$ .

I need to find a finite non cyclic galois extension of $C((T))$

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307392/finding-galois-group-of-function-field-extension).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde This is a question asked by me..

Comment: Yes, I know, for comparing. You can take the algebraic closure of $C((T))$. The absolute Galois group $Gal(\overline{C((T))}/C((T)))$ is not cyclic. It is not even finitely generated - see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99407/is-the-absolute-galois-group-of-the-field-of-laurent-series-in-positive-characte). Aaah, I see, you changed it to finite extension.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde OK, but i ment to find a finite extesion. Question edited..

Comment: [Here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6dd6/f43d382d5e8c6884d2486ccdac3baf4193f0.pdf) are examples with non-cyclic Galois group.

Comment: I already told you that you need to understand Hensel lemma, not only for separable polynomials $\bmod T$ but also for non-separable ones with roots in $C[[T]]/(T^n)$ with $n$ large enough.

Comment: @reuns Do you have any place to look at for a reference?